# How to create an input box (textbox) for a property of a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, model, shopping-cart

I have a simple shopping cart model which contains a list of items:

```
public class ShoppingCart
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public double Tax { get; set; }
    // ... some other properties
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public double TotalCost { get { return Quantity * Price; } }
}
```

I want to modify the quantity of a particular item and I've made the following View:

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("Recalculate", "ShoppingCart", Model))
  { %>
<table id="cartTable" border ="5px" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="5px" width="640">
    <tr>
        <td><b>Item Name</b></td>
        <td><b>Item Qty</b></td>
        <td><b>Item Price</b></td>
        <td><b>Subtotal</b></td>
    </tr>
    <%
    if (Model != null && Model.Items != null)
    {
        foreach (ShoppingCart.Models.Item item in Model.Items)
        {
            %>
            <tr>
                <td><%: item.Name%></td>
                <td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Items[Model.Items.IndexOf(item)], new { @Value = item.Quantity })%></td>
                <td><%: String.Format("{0:C}", item.Price)%></td>
                <td><%: String.Format("{0:C}", item.TotalCost)%></td>
            </tr>
            <%
        }
    } 
    %>
    <!-- some other rows/columns go here -->
</table> 
<input type="submit" value="Update Cart" />
<%} %>
```

And my controller:

```
public class ShoppingCartController : Controller
{

    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Show(ShoppingCart model)
    {
        if (model!= null && model.Items == null)
        {
            List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
            items.Add(new Item { Name = "Hat", Price = 20.0, Quantity = 1 });
            items.Add(new Item { Name = "Snowboard", Price = 430.0, Quantity = 1 });
            items.Add(new Item { Name = "Goggles", Price = 24.0, Quantity = 3 });

            model.Items = items;
            model.Tax = 6.5;
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Recalculate(ShoppingCart model)
    {
        if (model != null && model.Items!=null)
        {
            foreach (Item item in model.Items)
            {
                if (item.Quantity == 0)
                {
                    model.Items.Remove(item);
                }
                else if (item.Quantity < 0)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("error", "The quantity for " + item.Name + " must not be smaller than 0.");
                }
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Show", "ShoppingCart", model);
    }

}
```

Unfortunately when I click on the Update Cart button it calls my Recalculate function, but now all of the items in the Items list are null. How can I keep the items AND update the quantity of a given item?

In the BeginForm function I tried passing in the current model and not passing it a model at all... nothing changes. Could anybody help me figure this out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do these changes in appropriate locations and things would start working. Note that while the postback the Price and TotalCost would not be populated in the model as the corresponding rendered items are static text. These can be repopulated in the Controller or add hidden field in the view so that these can be posted and repopulated.

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("Recalculate", "ShoppingCart", FormMethod.Post))

<td><%: Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Items[Model.Items.IndexOf(item)].Quantity)%></td>

//return RedirectToAction("Show", "ShoppingCart", model);
return View("Show", model);
```

Comment: That was very helpful... and how are the other properties passed through the form? I don't want them to be editable, e.g. no need to edit the item name or the cost.

Comment: They are bound when outgoing, so display properly. But since they don't result in any element that is posted back, in the Recalculate those properties are not populated in the model. For this either repopulate those in the model (say from DB) or have hidden fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <%= Html.TextBox("Quantity", Model.Items[Model.Items.IndexOf(item)].Quantity ) %>
```

This is a nice blog post, worth a read: http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2010/03/13/asp-net-mvc-2-model-binding-for-a-collection.aspx